# Json file error

Tags: java, android, json

This is an error I believe I understand but its one Im stuck on how to fix. Im using a JSON file to help make skins for libgdx android programming. Theres 4 parts that im going to share with you, the JSON file, code, pack file, and error log.

JSON file:

```
{
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color": {
    "white": { "r": 1, "g": 1, "b": 1, "a": 1 },
    "black": { "r": 0, "g": 0, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
    "red":   { "r": 1, "g": 0, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
    "green": { "r": 0, "g": 1, "b": 0, "a": 1 },
    "blue":  { "r": 1, "g": 0, "b": 1, "a": 1 },
},
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
    "white": { "file": "font/white.fnt" },
    "black": { "file": "font/black.fnt" }
},
"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
    "default": { "font": white, "fontColor": white }
},
"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle": {
    "default": { "up": "button.up" , "down": "button.down", "font": black, "pressedOffsetX": 1, "pressedOffsetY": -1 }
},
"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle": {
    "default": { "font": white, "fontColorUnselected": white, "fontColorSelected": black, "selection": "default.selection" }
}}
```

Code:

```
    package com.me.mygdxgame.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;

public class LevelMenu implements Screen {

    private Stage stage;
    private Table table;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    private Skin skin;
    private List list;
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;
    private TextButton play, back;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/atlas.pack");
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/menuSkin.json"), atlas);

        table = new Table(skin);
        table.debug();

        list = new List(new String[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"} , skin);

        scrollPane = new ScrollPane(list, skin);

        play = new TextButton("PLAY", skin);
        play.pad(15);

        back = new TextButton("BACK", skin);
        back.pad(10);

        //Adding to table
        table.add("SELECT LEVEL");
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        atlas.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
    }

}
```

**Note the place where I use to to connect the atlas.pack and menuJson.json is in the skin constructor

Pack file:

```
    atlas.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
button.down
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 9
  size: 9, 9
  split: 2, 2, 2, 2
  orig: 9, 9
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
button.down
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 9
  size: 9, 9
  orig: 9, 9
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
button.up
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 9, 9
  split: 1, 2, 1, 2
  orig: 9, 9
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
button.up
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 9, 9
  orig: 9, 9
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
default.selection
  rotate: false
  xy: 9, 17
  size: 1, 1
  orig: 1, 1
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Error Log:

```
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: ui/menuSkin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:96)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:81)
    at com.me.mygdxgame.screens.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
    at com.me.mygdxgame.screens.Splash$1.onEvent(Splash.java:54)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.callCallback(BaseTween.java:380)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.updateStep(BaseTween.java:521)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween.update(BaseTween.java:424)
    at aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager.update(TweenManager.java:166)
    at com.me.mygdxgame.screens.Splash.render(Splash.java:28)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.me.mygdxgame.BlackPoint2.render(BlackPoint2.java:33)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:207)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: ui/menuSkin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:657)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:94)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Serialization trace:
selection (com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:757)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:860)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:410)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:804)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:431)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:420)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:416)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:834)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:410)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:655)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: default.selection
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.getDrawable(Skin.java:284)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.get(Skin.java:132)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:409)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:750)
    ... 23 more
```

I understand there is alot of files here, but I wanted to insure the most for the people answering questions. Any help is extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your json to fix it?

Comment: Yes I can edit my json, how do I need to edit it? @PopoFibo